# Angular - Test library before publish

Tags: angular, npm

I have created Angular library contain modules each module contain services.

I need to make a test If I change one of these services.

The question, Is there a good and simple way to test the library without the need to publish it and install it in the main project?.

Comment: Have you tried `npm link`?

Comment: I will try with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for yurzui, about the comment that show me the way.

I have used this, inside the library:

```
npm install
npm run build
npm link ./dist/<library_name>
```

and inside the project, I have removed the dependency and make:

```
npm install 
npm link <library_name>
npm start
```

---

There is also another way by copying the file to the library, I have do it by using a watcher that will run after building a library and copy it to the target project.